# Is there a fix for an iMac G5 annoying screen pattern issue?

Tags: display, mac

It's probably a hardware issue, but I was hoping that someone might know of other options to try. My iMac G5 (the revision just before the built-in iSight was introduced) has developed an annoying pattern of short/wide rectangles in a pinkish hue across the screen. I've followed Apple's instructions to ensure that the logic board hasn't failed (by resetting the SMU and watching the internal LEDs light-up). I suspect either the LCD or video card has failed. Below are two screen shots, one taken by my iPhone which exhibits the problem and a snapshot taking from the faulty iMac which looks fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would guess that it's a video card problem. Do the artifacts move about when what's on the screen changes? I don't think there's anything that can be done other than replace the hardware.

Comment: I suspected the video card as the artifacts do change when windows are moved about (or new windows appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most definitely your graphics adapter has died. I suggest you take it to a genius bar to see how much it would cost to get it fixed, or buy a new Mac.

Comment: I ended up buying a new Mac because they wanted almost $700 to replace the logic board.

Answer (score 0):

It's the capacitors on the logic card - there seems to be a generic fault, unless Apple will cover it for free, it's an economic write-off.

Comment: Apple will not cover it for free.

Comment: Well there was a warranty replacement but I think it's all done.
If you can solder (or you know someone who can) it's possible you can replace the capacitors.  But it's at least a couple of hours work.